# How can I check for a plus sign using regular expressions?

Tags: php

I'm trying to check for a plus sign using PHP and regular expressions.

Here is the code I got so far.

```
preg_replace('#[^-a-zA-Z0-9_&; ]#', '', $abcd)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You might just need to escape the plus sign with a backslash: `\+`.

Answer (score 0):

Add a + to the list.

```
preg_replace('#[^-a-zA-Z0-9_&; +]#', '', $abcd)
```